# JQuery Collision. Get collided elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, collision

I use the JQuery collision library :

[JQuery Collision example](http://eruciform.com/static//jquerycollision/jquery-collision-drag-collision-example.html)

My scenario :

a = object which is dragged.

b = object that should return a collision detection if collided.

*Every 100ms, on drag event of « a », I call a function that checks for collision with « b »

If « a » collide with « b », I can get the divs object poped by the library. But I cant find an easy way to get the elements(« b ») which are collided. I have a workaround for this but it's kinda to much so I'd like a shorten way directly from the library or so..

How can I get which of MY elements that are collided by those "poped" divs

Any ideas or suggestion? Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out what was my problem and it fixed my workaround pattern.

```
//returns an array of overlaps div elements (my problem)
 var overlaps = $("#selector").collision( ".isSomething", { as: "<div/>" } ); 


//returns an array of collided elements (the solutions)
var overlaps = $("#selector").collision( ".isAVisibleTree", { relative: "body", obstacleData: "odata", as: "<div/>" } );

//my collided object
overlaps[i].data("odata");
```

Hope it helps,

Marc